# PHP array to JavaScript array shows [object, object]

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have been trying to pass a PHP array to a JavaScript array, but when I read out the content of that JavaScript array it shows literally [object, object].

First I make an array in PHP from a sql statement, after that I change it into a JSON format and put it in a JavaScript array.

```
<?php     

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   $array[] = $row;
   }

mysql_free_result($result);

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    var js_array =<?php echo json_encode($array);?>;

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    alert(js_array[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem with that? It is an object after all.

Comment: Don't use `alert` as a debugging tool. Try `console.log(js_array)` and inspect your browser's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be your $array value is multi dimensional associated array which leads to json object array on json encoding. to view your array candidates, try

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
alert(JSON.stringify(js_array[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each row returned by the mysql_fetch_assoc is an associative array which is basically a hash "key/value" which is considered by json and javascript an object !

use mysql_fetch_array instead

mysql_fetch_array
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

mysql_fetch_assoc
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

$row as a mysql_query_result is already an array, so you fill your $array with arrays. That way js_array[0] is still an array, which is interpreted by JS as an object. You need another nested level in order to get to the individual values.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your php array contains something like:

```
$myArray = array( 'first' => 1, 'second' => 2 );
```

Now when you assign it to a javascript array with `json_encode`, like:

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode( $myArray ); ?>
```

It is equivalent to:

```
js_array = { "first" : "1", "second" : "2" }; // output of json_encode
```

So basically your `js_array` variable ***is*** an object.

You can view its contents like this:

```
console.log( js_array );
```